# setting logout invalidate-session to false

Tags: spring-security

I have a question about spring security. For my logout tag I have specified invalidate-session false like the following...

```
    <logout             
        invalidate-session="false" 
        delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" 
        success-handler-ref="customUrlLogoutSuccessHandler"/>
```

I need to do this because of something quirky with the concurrency-control session timeout tag. Unless I set invalidate-session to false i always get session timeout on my logout action.

My question is because I have set invalidate-session to false do I now need to invalidate the session programmatically somewhere? What are the repercussions of what I have done?

My application seems to log you out when you hit the logout button and I can't get it unless I log back in. So it seems like there might be nothing to do. But I can't help thinking that I need to do something more. I don't want to leave a back door to my application open.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The repercussions are that

- The HttpSession still exists but you no longer have a reference to it. It won't go away until the session times out. This means you have additional objects in memory
- If you store anything in the HttpSession and someone else managed to acquire the session id they can still use that session. Note that the user information is cleared out of the session, so this would only be relevant if you added the session

Comment: That's a great answer. Thanks. Is the best way to do this just to do a session.invalidate() in my custom logout handler?

Comment: The best way to invalidate the session is to use session.invalidate() in your custom logout handler. I guess my question to you is why does invalidating the session in your logouthandler work better than having Spring Security do it for you?